# ebean validation in play framework 2.5

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.5

I was looking at the sample code provided on their page :

```
@Entity
public class Task extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Min(10)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    public boolean done;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date dueDate = new Date();

    public static Finder<Long, Task> find = new Finder<Long,Task>(Task.class);
}
```

the @Constraints.Min(10) does not seem to be working. When I tried to develop my model with a constraints, it did not trigger the validation upon saving. sample code:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends Model{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(100)", nullable false)
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Constraints.MinLength(10)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(10)
    public String name;

}
```

and I tried to run this code :

```
Company company = new Company();

company.name="";
company.save()
```

it will save the data into the database although the name was empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The Constraints are for form binding validation, not direct field setting.

```
private static final Form<Company> companyForm = formFactory.form(Company.class);
```

So in the controller method that renders the view.

```
Form<Company> filledForm = companyForm.fill(company);
view.render(filledForm);
```

In the controller method that handles the form posting back to the server.

```
Form<Company> boundForm = companyForm.bindFromRequest();
if (boundForm.hasErrors()) {
    // This will happen if there is validation errors, you can also add a validate method to Company for more complex validation
    return badRequest(views.html.form.render(boundForm));
} else {
    Company company = boundForm.get();
    return ok("Got company " + company);
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to do field validation for ebean?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Seems you can use `javax.validation.constraints` constraints such as `@Size(min=10)` (for string etc lengths), or in your case (a number), `@Min(10)`  with modern versions of ebean.
I haven't tested it, but it seems like it will do what you want.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html